# JAXB Marshalling generic Tree

Tags: java, jaxb

I have a generic Tree with a rather classical implementation:

```
package tree;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

import tree.persistence.EdgesAdapter;
import tree.persistence.NodesAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Tree<N, E> {

    @XmlElement
    protected N root;

    /**
     * Map of nodes to adjacency outgoing of neighboring nodes to incident edges
     */
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(NodesAdapter.class)
    protected Map<N, Set<E>> nodes;

    /**
     * Map of edges to incident nodes pairs
     */
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(EdgesAdapter.class)
    protected Map<E, Pair<N>> edges;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private Tree() {
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public Tree(N root) {
        this.root = root;
        nodes = new HashMap<N, Set<E>>();
        edges = new HashMap<E, Pair<N>>();
        nodes.put(root, new HashSet<E>());
    }

    public boolean addEdge(E edge, N parent, N child) {
       //code to add edge and child node here...
    }
}
```

and Pair class:

```
package tree;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "pair")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Pair<N> {

    @XmlAttribute
    private N first;
    @XmlAttribute
    private N second;

    public Pair(N value1, N value2) {
        if (value1 == null || value2 == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Pair cannot contain null values");
        first = value1;
        second = value2;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        private Pair() {
    }

    public N getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public N getSecond() {
        return second;
    }

}
```

I have developped adapters so as to not have problems with structures like

```
Map<N, Set<E>>
```

and

```
Map<E, Pair<N>>.
```

But, when I try to Marshall a

```
Tree<String, Integer> tree
```

I have a null pointer exception:

```
@Test
public void testJAXBMarshaller() {

    File file = new File("Tree.xml");
    try {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Tree.class,
                Pair.class, String.class, Integer.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        jaxbMarshaller.setAdapter(new NodesAdapter());
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tree, file);
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tree, System.out);
    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        fail("testJAXBMarshaller " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is below the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor.get(TransducedAccessor.java:152)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.AttributeProperty.<init>(AttributeProperty.java:76)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:515)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementProperty.<init>(ArrayElementProperty.java:97)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.ArrayElementNodeProperty.<init>(ArrayElementNodeProperty.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:515)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.SingleElementNodeProperty.<init>(SingleElementNodeProperty.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.property.PropertyFactory.create(PropertyFactory.java:113)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.ClassBeanInfoImpl.<init>(ClassBeanInfoImpl.java:166)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getOrCreate(JAXBContextImpl.java:496)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:313)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1143)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:247)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:234)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:462)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:641)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at tree.TreeTest.testJAXBMarshaller(TreeTest.java:133)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

I just can't figure out where is my problem ?

Comment: `have a null pointer exception:` Can you, please, post exception details (line of code, stack trace)?

Answer (score 0):

The problem results from Pair.first and Pair.second being *private* fields.

a) You can make them public

b) Add public getters and use Accessor.PROPERTY.

Comment: I have not said it but Pair class has a private no-arg constructor. I tried the suggestion with Accessor.PROPERTY and public getters and i still have a null pointer exception.

Comment: I have not said it but Pair class has a private no-arg constructor and public getters. I tried the above suggestion with Accessor.PROPERTY and I still have a null pointer exception. I have updated the code above to show the actual code. Should I give the code for the adapters to further the analysis ?